# Xpath match node with slash in data using predicate

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate, slash

Problem originated while using SoapUI to validate xml response data.  I transfered the problem to XPath Visualizer so I could work through the issues.

Using an Xpath query I want to return the **b:AccountActivity** node that has the child node **b:ActivityDescription** value equal to 
'7.75000%10/30-11-10    $1602' from the xml excerpt below.

This is my xpath query:

```
//b:AccountActivity[b:ActivityDescription = "7.75000%10/30-11/10    $1602"]

    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <RetrieveAccountActivityResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <RetrieveAccountActivityResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:key xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntegratorSuite.DataContracts">
               <b:CurrentPage>0</b:CurrentPage>
               <b:Direction>Ascending</b:Direction>
               <b:PageSize>50</b:PageSize>
               <b:SortByParameter i:nil="true"/>
               <b:TotalEntries>4</b:TotalEntries>
               <b:TotalPages>1</b:TotalPages>
            </a:key>
            <a:value xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntegratorSuite.DataContracts">
               <b:AccountActivity>
                  <b:AccountNumber>11111111</b:AccountNumber>
                  <b:AccountType>2</b:AccountType>
                  <b:ActivityDescription>7.75000%10/30-11/10    $1602</b:ActivityDescription>
                  <b:Amount>4.1200000000</b:Amount>
                  <b:CallPut_HasValue>false</b:CallPut_HasValue>
                  <b:CallPut_Value>ALL</b:CallPut_Value>
                  <b:CmpQualCode i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:Currency>USD</b:Currency>
                  <b:Cusip></b:Cusip>
                  <b:Description1/>
                  <b:Description2/>
                  <b:EntryType>DC</b:EntryType>
                  <b:ExpirationDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</b:ExpirationDate>
                  <b:JournalDescription i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:NetAmount>-4.1200000000</b:NetAmount>
                  <b:Price>0.000000</b:Price>
                  <b:PrincipalAmount>-4.1200000000</b:PrincipalAmount>
                  <b:Quantity>0.000000</b:Quantity>
                  <b:RecordType>H</b:RecordType>
                  <b:RootSymbol i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:SecQualCode i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:SecurityDescription>Cash</b:SecurityDescription>
                  <b:SecurityGroupCategoryID>0</b:SecurityGroupCategoryID>
                  <b:SecurityGroupDescription i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:SecurityQuantityConversion>0</b:SecurityQuantityConversion>
                  <b:SecurityTypeCode i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:StockConversionFactor>0</b:StockConversionFactor>
                  <b:StrikePrice>0.0</b:StrikePrice>
                  <b:Symbol/>
                  <b:SymbolCusip i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:TableID i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:TradeDate_HasValue>true</b:TradeDate_HasValue>
                  <b:TradeDate_Value>2010-11-11T00:00:00</b:TradeDate_Value>
                  <b:TradeDetailID_HasValue>false</b:TradeDetailID_HasValue>
                  <b:TradeDetailID_Value>0</b:TradeDetailID_Value>
                  <b:TradeNumber i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:TransactionType>Interest Collected</b:TransactionType>
                  <b:UnderlyingCusip i:nil="true"/>
                  <b:UnderlyingSymbol i:nil="true"/>
               </b:AccountActivity>
               <b:AccountActivity>
               ...
```

It appears that the forward slash in the node value is what is causing the match to fail.  If I remove those from the xml and xpath query i get a match. Is there some issue with matching slashes in node values?  Seem like a fundamental question but I can't find an answer.

Comment: That's a bit odd, isn't it. I don't think xpath has a way of escaping the content of strings other than quotes (which you have to double up). Does this work: `//b:AccountActivity[b:ActivityDescription.text()="7.75000%10/30-11/10 $1602"]`? I don't think it should make any difference but it could be worth a try.

Comment: @allen: literal forward slash has nothing to do with your problem. Your XPath expression has the riht syntax. Maybe the problem is in the code you haven't provided. Are namespaces prefix binded to the right namespace URI?

Comment: @Andrew - yes I tried double quotes to no avail.

Comment: @Alejandro - I added the top part of the document with the namespaces to the post.  I have several other matches for fields in the same namespace that are working fine, and the match works for this field if the data in the field does not have slashes so I am pretty sure it comes back to the slashes somehow.

Comment: @Andrew: I cannot repro this problem. I am using the XPath Visualizer and it selects the required element.

Comment: What version of XPath Visualizer are you using? There is one at http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/ and another at topxml.com. Which are you using?

Comment: @LarsH - I am using codeplex version 1.2.1.6 XPath Visualizer. But it also fails in SoapUI 3.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in the xml document below (way below) the portion I posted (as Alejandro suggested).  The namespace URI for the element being queried was being redefined to a different URI later in the document. Once the second namespace was changed to a different unique name the xpath works as expected.  For some reason redefining the URI later in the document caused the abnormal behavior in some xpath tools and not others when field data above the desired node had a slash in it. Thanks for everyones input. Next time I will post the entire document :).

Answer (score 1):

**I cannot reproduce this**:

[image]

Comment: Well, could be the difference in version.  I am using 1.2.1.6 desktop version of XPath Visualizer. But it also fails in SoapUI 3.5.1.

Comment: @allen: You must be talking about some other, completely different tool. I *am* the author of the XPath Visualizer and there are no such things like "desktop version" or version 1.2.1.6. Anything that calls itself "XPath Visualizer" and is not the real tool is obviously quite unreliable... :)

Comment: @allen: Sure this is a fake :). The true XPath Visualizer is here: http://www.topxml.com/xpathvisualizer Be aware that this site is a ghost and there is a lot of malware. Dont access this link if you dont have a good anti-malware tool installed.

Comment: @Dimitre: You should upload your excellent application to a better host, I think.

Comment: @Alejandro: Fully agreed. I even asked if somebody would offer their site, but ... never received a response to this.

Comment: @Dimitre: What do you think about these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories

Comment: @Dimitre, does the One True XPath Visualizer require server-side scripting, or is it js-only?

Comment: @LarsH: It is client-side only -- just Javascript and XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0):

As Alejandro pointed out in his comment to the question, the namespace binding is not working in all the tools I used to test this xpath (except xmlspy). However the following xpath did work (I simply ignored the namespaces).

```
//*[local-name()='AccountActivity' and ./*[local-name()='ActivityDescription' and text()='7.75000%10/30-11/10    $1602']]
```

Comment: Greg, thanks for your input, but unfortunately, I can't get this one to work either.  I don't mean to sound like a broken record but the only thing that breaks this xpath query is if there is a /(slash) in the field data.  This field does not always return data with slashes and when it doesn't have slashes in it the match works perfectly (with the namespaces). Even with the example you provided here it works if I have data in that field without slashes.  If there is some problem with the namespaces can someone suggest what is wrong and how to fix the namespaces?